# php delete file that contains '& characters'

Tags: php, file, unlink

i have string path like this "../music/Safe & Sound.mp3"

but when i tried to delete the file with PHP like this

```
if (!unlink($path))
{
    echo "Error while deleting file";exit();
}
```

it shows the echo "Error while deleting file" and file failed to be deleted
i have tried to rename the file manually by removing "&" character, unlink works perfectly

so how to delete a file using unlink with special character such as "&" on its filename?

Comment: How are you creating `$path` variable and populating it. Please add that bit of code as well.

Comment: $path="../music/Safe & Sound.mp3"
i use that '..' because the file is in another folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try by following script

```
$path = '../music/Safe \& Sound.mp3'; /* I don't know about complete path I just want to let you know about file name */
if (!unlink($path))
{
    echo "Error while deleting file";exit();
}
```

`\` will escape the special character.

Comment: is there any method to add that slash automatically? i have tried addslashes but it's not working

Comment: addslashes($path)